# What's the likelihood of a large tx being included into a block

Tags: transactions, mining, consensus, validators

I know that on Ethereum, each block has a target size of 15 million gas, and a block size limit of 30 million.

If I send a multicall transaction that will consume around 15 million gas, with the proper priority fee, is it possible to be picked by miner and included into block? Or the priority of such transaction will be lower due to consensus logic?

If so then how do I increase the likelihood of such transaction to be mined? By increase the priority fee more?

Thanks